# Filter message body and i get force close

Tags: java, android, string, sms, prefix

I want to filter messages with the prefix "kmsmks", compile success but I get force close:

```
...
        String firstword = "kmsmks";

        while  (cursor.moveToNext()) 
        {   String address = cursor.getString(1);
            String body = cursor.getString(3);

            String firstmessageword = body.substring(0,7);

         if (firstword.equals(firstmessageword))

            {
                   System.out.println("======> Mobile number => "+address);
                   System.out.println("=====> SMS Text => "+body);

                   sms.add("Address=> "+address+"\n SMS => "+body);   
               }

        }
        return sms;
    }
…
```

original code : http://www.technotalkative.com/android-fetch-inbox-sms/

Comment: Could you post the stack trace for the error?

Comment: I looked at your original code, and just so you know, you shouldn't be calling `cur.getString(1)` on your cursor. Instead, you should be determining the column indexes at runtime with `cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("column_name"));`. Doing so will ensure your code doesn't break if you ever decide to alter your database structure.

Comment: @SagarHatekar : No Error, but force close :(

Comment: @AlexLockwood : Oh, that code is not optimized? Sorry, Im newbie..

Comment: (1) It's not that it isn't optimized... it's just not good coding practice and will make your life more difficult down the line. (2) A force close is most certainly an error... check your logcat and post the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added `android.permission.READ_SMS` in manifest

Comment: Thanks 4 answers.. but working if i delete "String firstword = "kmsmks";" and "if (firstword.equals(firstmessageword))" but i want filter message with prefix.. (sorry bad english)